# Why does my book say that "since a major change takes place at (1,1), the expression in the absolute value should equal to zero at x=1?

Tags: absolute-value

Question I am referring to:
[image]

Why does the absolute value portion of the expression of the function this graph corresponds to has to be 0 when x=1?

Here are the five choices:
[image]

Comment: I think you must have omitted some context. I am guessing that you are plotting something like $x \mapsto {1 \over 2} (x-1 + |x-1|)$, and hence it is saying that you must have $|x-1| = 0$ at $x=1$. Why, I have no idea.

Comment: @copper.hat, there are five choices. I think they don't matter.

Comment: I think the 'major change' is misleading. Some detective work is needed. I would look at $x=0$ which eliminates (A),(E), then $x=-1$ which eliminates (C) and then $x=2$ which eliminates (D). Then use the Conan Doyle principle.

Comment: Well, (B) is the only guy non-differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: As an aside, many things are 'obvious' when you know them.

Comment: @Christoph's answer is more sophisticated.

Comment: He know the answer but he is asking why the book said major changes in absolute values happened at the zeros of the function which include an absolute value right ?

Comment: @Ameryr, yes I figured out the answer by plugging in. But the book throws me off by saying out of no where that since the "major change" happen at (1,1), the expression in the absolute value signs should be equal to 0.

Comment: If we have a function like this $f(x) = |g(x)| + h(x)$ does this function has a major change at the zeros of $g(x)$ ? This is the question

Comment: Yes, it has a major change when $g(x) = 0$ as long as $g(x) \neq 0$ close to the zeros of $g(x)$. Please consider the answer I posted 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I think there should be conditions on $g,h$ continuous and differentiable. Or if they just linear

Comment: If $g$ and $h$ were not differentiable then there would be major changes at every point where they are not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer B is correct. You know that the function is a sum of two different functions, a linear function and an absolute value function.

The absolute value function $f(x) = |g(x)|$ has a major change when $f(x) = 0$. But in this graph, there is a major change at $x = 1$, so $f(x) = 0$ at $x = 1$, and the absolute value function must be translated by one unit to the right to make the function work. In other words, $g(x) = x - 1$ (translated one unit to the right), and the answer with the $f(x) = |x-1|$ term is correct.

Comment: How do you see from jus the graph that it's sum of a linear and absolute value?

Comment: Yep, because the major change you see at $(1,1)$ is characteristic of an absolute value function. If the slope of the absolute value function is the same as the slope of a linear function, then you'll end up with a constant function on one side, and a function with double the slope on the other side.

Comment: Is what u stated a theorem? How adding one absolute to a linear will result in doubling the slope of the absolute one.

Comment: Sorry, you keep editing your comments so I'll reply to your edited question. Consider the function $f(x) = x + |x|$. When $x < 0$, $f(x) = 0$, and when $x > 0$, $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: More importantly, all your answer choices only involve absolute value and linear functions!